# Spring MVC: No message found under code 'label.description' for locale 'en_us'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I'm trying to implement internationalisation on my project, however I cannot resolve my BaseName, so far this is my AppConfiguration class methods:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new           ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();`
    messageSource.setBasename("messages/");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en_US"));
    resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
    resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("mylocale");
    registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}
```

And this is my project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LI9T.png)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I also trying to change my baseName to `classpath:messages` but nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
```

}

and rename your `en_us.properties` to `messages_en_us.properties`

Comment: Still the same error: `javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.description' for locale 'en_us'`

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to your application.properties

spring.messages.basename=validation